# Sort NSFileManager Results

Tags: cocoa, macos, sorting, nsfilemanager

I am wondering how to get a NSFileManager listing to display the results in the order that the Finder sorts them.  By default, this code:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

NSError *foundErrors = nil;

NSArray *contentsOfDockDirectory = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"/Users/me/Desktop error:&foundErrors];
```

Generates a NSArray that lists it in this type of order: 1, 100, 2, 200, etc.  However, the Finder shows it in it's correct sorting so it's: 1, 2, 100, 200, etc.

Is there some way to sort either NSArray or NSFileManager in order to have the listing in this order?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a section in the String Programming Guide called ["Sorting strings like Finder"](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/SearchingStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000149-SW1), which is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks!  It works great!  Just asking though, but is that code open source and is it necessary that I give credit?

Comment: Apple's license for code samples is on the longer code samples, and it may apply to the smaller snippets, too. More usefully, if that's a worry, I'd just read the snippet and learn the technique, then write my own original code with that technique.

Comment: @Martin Is there a way to maintain the manual sorting you do in the finder?